# How can i stop the package with more than 1 dataflow if the first fail?

Tags: ssis

I've a SSIS package with more than 1 data Flow, If the 1st Dataflow fail I don't want to execute the follows. How can I stop the execution of the package. I tried using red arrow  and script task doing nothing but I it doesn't work.   the others dataflows are executed as well getting all the errors to my .net client. I need only the error for the Data flow that fail.

Anyone know how can I get it
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `MaximumErrorCount` To `1` on your `data flow task`, but this is the default value. Same goes for the value at package level, if you set this to `1`, the package terminates with error if you task fails.

But as i said, these are default values and you shouldn't have anything to do. Do you execute the `data flow tasks` all together? If you do, build one path which executes all the tasks after another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Squence Container and put all the data flow task in it. I have shared the screen shot of the sample, adjust the priority for all the data flow task and put sucess condition for the tasks.

[image]